# Docker build does not remove temporary images when building a multi-stage docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that builds my .Net Core API in a temporary image and then creates an image with the generated files. As far as I know, the temporary image should be removed automatically but in my tests it was not removed. I use Docker Desktop for Windows. The docker file, image list before running it and after running it are as follows;

Docker file;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreAPI1.dll"]
```

Image list before running;

```
PS D:\temp\CoreAPI1\CoreAPI1> docker image ls                                                                           
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk      2.2-alpine          3a2253204e79        4 weeks ago         1.48GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet   2.2-alpine          820b2f3a9c7a        4 weeks ago         168MB
PS D:\temp\CoreAPI1\CoreAPI1>
```

Commands tested;

```
docker build -t coreapi1 .
docker build --rm -t coreapi1 .
```

Image list after building the docker file;

```
PS D:\temp\CoreAPI1\CoreAPI1> docker image ls                                                                           
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
coreapi1                               latest              d8cb00730c52        3 minutes ago       168MB
<none>                                 <none>              1105d14991b3        3 minutes ago       1.48GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk      2.2-alpine          3a2253204e79        4 weeks ago         1.48GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet   2.2-alpine          820b2f3a9c7a        4 weeks ago         168MB
PS D:\temp\CoreAPI1\CoreAPI1>
```

See the image with name and tag **none**.

Docker version is 19.03.2. 
What may be the reason? 
How can I prevent this dangling image being left after the build?

Comment: `docker build --rm -t image_tag .`

Comment: @Adiii this did not work. I still see the temp image after the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for image in $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
do
    docker rmi -f $image
done
```

or `docker images -q -f "dangling=true" | xargs docker rmi`

The key here is the `"dangling=true"` filter, which shows exactly those intermediary images used during the building stage.

Comment: the code is ok, but I want the temporary image to be deleted automatically after the build completes. Is it possible or removing dangling images with extra command is the only way?

Comment: @NthDeveloper it's the only way. Docker doesn't provide any built-in solution because removing such intermediary images defeats the main purpose of a multistage build: cache those images to speed up the process.

Answer (score -2):

```
docker image rm [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

Options

```
--force , -f        Force removal of the image
--no-prune      Do not delete untagged parents
```

Comment: I do not know the id of the automatically created temporary image and the question is how to prevent it.